# Report builder 3: moving average (calculated series) only looks at non-empty months

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I have the following chart:

- X-axis: months
- Y-axis: number of orders

The chart shows the number of orders per month: each month one column.

I want to add a line to the chart showing a "moving 3 months total" using a calculated series (using moving average).

First I created an extra series which does (month total)*3, and which I hide in the chart.

Then I created a calculated series that does a moving average of period =3 on the second series.
Indeed as a result I get a line with moving 3 months total.

Problem: when there are months with no data, the moving average series "ignores" those months. 
Suppose we have the following situation:

- jan: 4
- feb: 7
- mar: 5
- apr: 0  (= no data)
- may: 5

Then in month "mar" the line shows "16", which is correct (4 +7 +5).
But month "may" shows 17 instead of 10. It includes the non-empty months may, mar and feb, instead of looking at the 3 months period mar-apr-may (which are on the x-axis).

According to [this Report builder information page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207034.aspx) the moving average takes the time period when the x-axis is a time scale. In my case it doesn't...

The reason I think is because group "mar" is missing, there are no records for that month.
That's why even setting the EmptyPointValue = Zero on the second series doesn't help anything. The chart doesn't show months with missing data as zero Y values, but interconnects non-zero values of non-empty/non-missing months.

Anybody knows how I can solve this without creating dummy records for the missing months?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found to this problem:

- make sure that my dataset result contains one "dummy" record for each month (data
  may be null). I did this by joining a table containing a list of months (first of month) with
  my data table and use that as input for my dataset
- write my dataset/chart filters in such a way that those "dummy" records are
  always present in the result set

In short, make sure not to have "missing" months in my dataset result.